# Как сравнить каждый элемент массива друг с другом, не сравнивая один и тот же элемент?

Tags: java, алгоритм

К примеру, у меня есть массив `String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}`, и я хочу сравнить элемент `arr[0]` с каждым элементом массива `arr` через вложенный цикл, но как мне избежать сравнения элемента `arr[i]` с самим собой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно начинать вложенный цикл с индекса `i + 1`

```js
   arr = [1,2,3,4];
   for (i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) 
        for (j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) 
            console.log(arr[i], arr[j]);
```

Comment: Тогда же, если i = 1, вложенный цикл начнётся со 2 элемента и пропустит нулевой элемент

Comment: Нулевой элемент будет сравнен со всеми другими на первой итерации внешнего цикла, на следующих итерациях в этом нужды уже нет

Comment: Извините, туплю. Спасибо, оказалось, что всё довольно просто.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i != j && arr[i].equals(arr[j])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String[] strings1 = new String[strings.length - 1];
System.arraycopy(strings, 0, strings1, 0, i);
System.arraycopy(strings, i + 1, strings1, i, strings1.length - i);
for (String s : strings1)
    if (strings[i].equals(s)) {
        // что-то
    }
```